# Update component within handleClick React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am having problem with updating/changing state of the components. Here is the code which i am trying to make work:

```js
class NavbarList extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const {id} = event.target;
    console.log(id);

 return <h3 id={1} onClick={this.onClick}>New Text</h3>
  }
 render() {
  return ( 
   <h3 id={0} onClick={this.onClick}>Old Text</h3>
 )};
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavbarList  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Examples with coditional rendering did not cleared it out for me.

I need more exmaples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of returning a new JSX element, you could use the state to save id and text, then update the state on click.

```js
class NavbarList extends React.Component {
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      text: "Old Text",
      id: 0
    };
    this.onClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const {id} = event.target;
    console.log(id);

    this.setState({
       text: "New text",
       id: 1
    });
  }

  render() {
     return ( 
         <h3 id={this.state.id} onClick={this.onClick}>{this.state.text}</h3>
  )};
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <NavbarList  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```