# how to set a isActive attribute dynamic with tabs clicked React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is a tab and I want to set the background color when it is active. How to write a function to change tabs using React.

```
`<Tabs
   className={classes.tabs}
   label={this.state.label}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
 >
 <Tab
  isActive={true ? this.state.label === "Monitor":undefined}
  label="Monitor"
  icon={<Icon icon="moon" />}
 />
</Tabs>`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing state of component with OnClick in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45134254/changing-state-of-component-with-onclick-in-react)

Comment: No it is different. I have three tabs.